# Let $X$ be a complete metric space. $E$ is a non empty open set in $X$ Then is $E$ a first category set or second category set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, baire-category, the-baire-space

Let $X$ be a complete metric space. $E$ is a non-empty open subset of $X$

Then is $E$ a first category set or a second category set. it seems to me that $E$ should be a second category set, but how to prove that .

or my guess is wrong ?
Any hint

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is completely metrisable too, so it's a second category set.

Direct sketch of proof for the former: If $d$ is a complete metric on $X$ then $$d_1(x,y):=d(x,y)+ \left|\frac{1}{d(x,X\setminus E)} - \frac{1}{d(y,X\setminus E)}\right|$$

is a complete metric for $E$ (in its subspace topology), or use a general theorem that a $G_\delta$ subset of a completely metrisable space is completely metrisable, if your text covers that fact.

**Added**: this not the whole story yet: we need an extra argument to show it is second category in $X$ too, using the openness in a different way:

If $N$ is nowhere dense in $X$ and $N \subseteq E$, then $N$ is nowhere dense in $E$ too. If not, $\overline{N}^{(E)} = \overline{N}^{(X)} \cap E$ would have non-empty interior, and as $E$ is open this cannot happen.

It follows that $E$ is not second category in $X$ because it would be second category in itself, which we saw above it is not.

Comment: I think this does not answer the question.  For example: A singeton $\{0\}$ in $\mathbb R$ is completely metrizable.  But $\{0\}$ is not of category in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @GEdgar. I concur that there is a missing step. If $E=\cup F$ where $F$ is a countable family of nowhere-dense subsets of $X$, then each $f\in F$ is nowhere-dense in the space $E$ because $E$ is open in $X.$ This does not apply for a non-open subset of $X$ such as  $\{0\}$.

Comment: In the proof of the general theorem, one step is to show that if $F$ is a countable family of completely metrizable subspaces of the completely metrizable space $X,$ then $\cap F$ is completely metrizable. I noticed that the only use of $X$ in this step is that $X$ is $T_2$. I was able to find an example of a $T_1$ (but not $T_2$) space with two completely metrizable subspaces $A,B$ such that $A\cap B$ is NOT completely metrizable.

Comment: I really like this answer because it doesn't just say "strong version of Baire Category Theorem." It shows that the statement "complete metric spaces are non-meager in themselves" implies "all complete metric spaces are Baire (all non-empty open subsets are non-meager in the containing space)"