# Example of a metric space that is non-meager itself and not Baire?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

Is there an example of a metric space that is not Baire and non-meager in itself?

I know that that complete metric spaces Baire spaces and that Baire topological spaces are non-meager in themselves. So the example must be an incomplete metric space.

I also that topological groups that are non-meager in themselves are Baire. So the example cannot be a topological group.

Here is something somewhat related. It shows that the statement "complete metric spaces are non-meager in themselves" implies "complete metric spaces are Baire":

- [Let $X$ be a complete metric space. $E$ is a non empty open set in $X$ Then is $E$ a first category set or second category set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254279/let-x-be-a-complete-metric-space-e-is-a-non-empty-open-set-in-x-then-is)

Comment: Since these are both global properties, can't we just "combine counterexamples" - e.g. $(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})\cup(\mathbb{Q}\times\{1\})$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual metric? The non-Baireness lives on the $\mathbb{Q}$-part and the non-self-meager-ness lives on the $\mathbb{R}$-part.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the disjoint union of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ (say
$ X:= \mathbb{R}\times\{0\} \cup \mathbb{Q} \times \{1\}$ with the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Clearly, $X \setminus \{ (q,1) \}$ is open dense for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ but $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\} = \bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} X \setminus \{ (q,1) \}$ is not dense. Hence, $X$ is no Baire space.

However, $X$ is non-meager because it contains a homeomorphic copy of $\mathbb{R}$, that is closed in $X$ (the latter is crucial).

If $X=\bigcup_n A_n$ with $A_n$ nowhere dense, then $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\} = \bigcup_n A_n \cap (\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})$. Since $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ is closed $A_n \cap (\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ as well. Hence $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ would be meager in $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$, which is a contradiction to Baire's category Theorem.

Comment: I just saw, you got the same answere, when I was typing. But I don't delete it, bc maybe the more details are helpful